# Is asking for ideas/suggestions off topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I've got an interesting question on game development that would be sure to stir up some discussion. Though the question is more on the lines of "what are some ideas on making a game of this genre".

It seems very broad, even for me. I wonder if this SE is the best to ask a question like that?

Comment: This isn't a discussion site, it's a Q&A site. There are other sites better suited for discussion. http://reddit.com/r/gamedev or http://gamedev.net

Answer (score 4):

> It seems very broad...

Broad questions get closed since there's no concrete answer.

You could try asking in the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development).

Comment: I'd add that there is a section titled _Where can I ask subjective, discussion, and other questions not fit for this site?_ on the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) help page which suggests other alternatives.